# Using a newer OS ipad for adhoc deployment

Tags: ios, adhoc

I'm getting confused about version compatibility and hoping someone can clear this up for me.

I have xcode 3.2.4 which supports iOS 3.2 but not 4.2.1.  Now, I have two iPads--and older 3.2 OS and a newer 4.2.1.  I am able to create an adhoc provision and install my app into my older iPad, but I cannot do it for my newer 4.2.1 iPad.  Shouldn't the newer ones be backward compatible at least in terms of running ad hoc distributions?

I get the yellow dot warning/error in Organizer when I hook up my new iPad and it says I need to install the latest iOS sdk to use my new iPad for development, but I'm wondering if there is something else I'm doing wrong.  It doesn't seem like I should have to keep upgrading my xcode to run ad hocs built for older OS's, much like old applications in the app store should just work for them.  Am I thinking about this incorrectly, or do I have to upgrade my iOS sdk just to build out ad hoc to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To develop on the newer iPad, you need a more up-to-date sdk. However, if all you want to do is run the ad-hoc build on it, then you just need to:

1. Add the UDID for the new iPad to your ad-hoc provisioning profile
2. Add the provisioning profile to your new iPad using iTunes
3. Add the ad-hoc release of your app to your iPad using iTunes

Comment: That's what I suspected should work. I added my udid as a device, added the device to my adhoc provision, dragged the file to my xcode, dragged it also to my itunes icon.  Then, I built the app and dragged the .app file to my itunes.  Does that sound right?  If it does, it's what I did, so my next question is whether there is a way to verify.  Maybe I should remove the provision and re-add it to xcode.

Comment: removing the provision, restarting xcode, and readding the provision did the trick, so people hung up like I was can try doing that.  I also removed the app from itunes before dragging the new one to it, so am uncertain if that was an important step to get it working.